# Shift Rows in Pandas Dataframe by Condition?

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, shift

I have the following dataframe:

import pandas as pd

```
data = [['Construction', '', '01/02/2022', '01/06/2022', '1', 'No'], ['Level Site', 'Construction', '01/02/2022', '01/02/2022', '2', 'No'], ['Foundation', '', '01/03/2023', '01/06/2023', '1', 'Yes'],['Lay Foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022', '3', 'No'], ['Prepare land for foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022', '3', 'No'],['Building Envelope', '', '01/07/2023', '01/16/2023', '1', 'No'], ['Install Footings', 'Building Envelope', '01/07/2022', '01/07/2022', '2', 'Yes'], ['Pouring', '', '01/08/202', '01/09/2023', '1', 'No'],['Pour Foundation', 'Building Envelope>Pouring', '01/08/2022', '01/09/2022', '3', 'No'], ['Installation', '', '01/09/2022', '01/14/2022', '1', 'No']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Activity', 'Parent', 'Start', 'Finish', 'WBS Level', 'Match'])

df1
```

#Ideal dataframe output

```
data = [['Construction', '', '01/02/2022', '01/06/2022', '1', 'No'],['Foundation', '', '01/03/2023', '01/06/2023', '1', 'Yes'], ['Level Site', 'Construction', '01/02/2022', '01/02/2022', '2', 'No'], ['Lay Foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/03/2022', '01/04/2022', '3', 'No'], ['Prepare land for foundation', 'Construction>Foundation', '01/05/2022', '01/06/2022', '3', 'No'],['Install Footings', 'Building Envelope', '01/07/2022', '01/07/2022', '2', 'Yes'],['Building Envelope', '', '01/07/2023', '01/16/2023', '1', 'No'], ['Pouring', '', '01/08/202', '01/09/2023', '1', 'No'],['Pour Foundation', 'Building Envelope>Pouring', '01/08/2022', '01/09/2022', '3', 'No'], ['Installation', '', '01/09/2022', '01/14/2022', '1', 'No']]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Activity', 'Parent', 'Start', 'Finish', 'WBS Level', 'Match'])

df2
```

I am prepping this data for use in a scheduling software application, and need to re-order the rows based on certain conditions.  I created the 'match' column for this purpose (I have already created my condition, any row that is 'yes' has fulfilled the condition).

For any row that has a 'yes' value in the 'match' column I want to shift up one row.  I have tried the variations of the .shift method but I'm having trouble getting it right.  I don't want to delete or override any rows, I just need to shift any 'yes' rows up by 1.

Thank you for your help

Comment: please provide an example of the output you would like to get. In a better readable format if possible, with the match column included.

Comment: I re-formatted my post @BluegirlFK, hopefully it's more readable.  I also added the match column and ideal output dataframe (df2).  You can see that the 'Foundation' and 'Install Footings' rows were shifted up one level in df2 as they contained a 'yes' in the match column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that swaps the rows required using indices rather than using `.shift()` (since it's not clear to me how you'd do this within a `groupby()`). Might not scale hugely well but should do the job on smaller datasets.

```
df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)  # ensure index is unique

# Loop through only the indices of rows to be shifted, to avoid looping through every row
shift_indices = df1[df1['Match'] == 'Yes'].index
for shift_idx in shift_indices:
    # No need to shift if at the top
    if shift_idx == 0:
        continue
    above_idx = shift_idx - 1
    above_row = df1.loc[above_idx].copy()  # copy as otherwise this row will change during the shift
    # If the row above is also a match, then no need to swap it
    if above_row['Match'] != 'Yes':
        shift_row = df1.loc[shift_idx]
        df1.loc[above_idx] = shift_row
        df1.loc[shift_idx] = above_row
```

Comment: The code above worked for my sample dataset @Marcus Boyle , but when I applied it to my larger dataframe (96 rows) I'm getting the following error:  "The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Comment: Sounds like the issue could be that the index is non-unique (i.e., multiple rows have the same index value), meaning that the `above_row` logic is pulling out more than one row at a time. I've added a line to the start that would address that scenario (resetting the index), hopefully it addresses your issue.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you so much!  I was having issues with it putting the 'yes' rows more than once above where it was supposed to be, but that was only because I was running the script more than once.  I was scratching my head on this for a few weeks now, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

IIUC and your input dataframe has the default ranged indexing, then you can do it by subtracting 1.5 from each index where 'Yes' and resorting the dataframe by new index:

```
df1.set_index(df1.index-np.where(df1['Match'] =='Yes', 1.5, 0)).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
                      Activity                     Parent       Start      Finish WBS Level Match
0                 Construction                             01/02/2022  01/06/2022         1    No
1                   Foundation                             01/03/2023  01/06/2023         1   Yes
2                   Level Site               Construction  01/02/2022  01/02/2022         2    No
3               Lay Foundation    Construction>Foundation  01/03/2022  01/04/2022         3    No
4  Prepare land for foundation    Construction>Foundation  01/05/2022  01/06/2022         3    No
5             Install Footings          Building Envelope  01/07/2022  01/07/2022         2   Yes
6            Building Envelope                             01/07/2023  01/16/2023         1    No
7                      Pouring                              01/08/202  01/09/2023         1    No
8              Pour Foundation  Building Envelope>Pouring  01/08/2022  01/09/2022         3    No
9                 Installation                             01/09/2022  01/14/2022         1    No
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df1['Match'] == 'Yes'
df1.loc[mask, 'Activity':'Match'], df1.loc[mask.shift(-1, fill_value=False), 'Activity':'Match'] = df1.loc[mask.shift(-1, fill_value=False), 'Activity':'Match'].values, df1.loc[mask, 'Activity':'Match'].values
```

Here's another way which is not very fast but still does the job:

```
for i, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Match'] == 'Yes':
        print(i)
        df1.iloc[i], df1.iloc[i-1] =  df1.iloc[i-1].copy(), df1.iloc[i].copy()
```